# Prove the probability that there are an odd number of black balls chosen in $N$ draws is $\frac{1}{2}\left(1-(1-\frac{2M}{N+M})^{N}\right)$

Tags: probability

Consider a bag of $N$ white balls and $M$ black balls. Now we draw a ball with replacement $N$ times. Then, prove that the probability that there are an odd number of black balls chosen in these $N$ draws is $$\frac{1}{2}\left(1-(1-\frac{2M}{N+M})^{N}\right)$$

I don't think the last step is correct but the previous steps are probably right.
My approach:
The first step [image: 1]
The second step [image: 2]
The last step [image: 3]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that $P_N(E | B) = P_{N-1}(E^c) = 1 - P_{N-1}(E)$ and $P_N(E | W) = P_N(E)$.

So, you would have (I'm not sure why you have a $N$-th power in your denomitator at this step):

$$P_N(E) =  ( 1 - P_{N-1}(E)) \frac{M}{N+M} + P_N(E) \frac{N}{N+M}$$

which can be rewritten as, denoting $p_N = P_N(E)$,

$$p_N = p_{N-1}\cdot \left(\frac{N-M}{N+M}\right)+\frac{M}{N+M}$$

with $p_0 = 0$.

For ease of use, let's denote $a=\frac{N-M}{N+M}$ and $b=\frac{M}{N+M}$. So we need to solve $p_N = ap_{N-1}+b$ with $p_0=0$.

In France, we call this kind of sequence ["arithmetico-geometric"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suite_arithm%C3%A9tico-g%C3%A9om%C3%A9trique) (different from [the English use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence)) and there is a simple method to solve those kind of equations.

Define $r$ as the fixed point of $f(x)=ax+b$ (so $p_{n+1}=f(p_n)$) - therefore $r=\frac{b}{1-a}$; with $a\neq 1$ since $M\neq 0$.

Then, define $u_n = p_n -r$. We have $u_{n+1} = p_{n+1}-r = f(p_n)-r = ap_n +b -r$. But since $r=ar+b$, $u_{n+1}=a(p_n-r)=au_n$ (the $b$'s cancel each other one out). $u_n$ is therefore a geometric sequence, whose general term is $u_n = a^n u_0$. So you end up with $p_n = a^n (p_0 - r) +r$.

Let's go back to the notations of the problem: $$r = \frac{\frac{M}{N+M}}{1-\frac{N-M}{N+M}}= \frac{M}{(N+M)-(N-M)}=\frac{1}{2}$$

so that $P_N(E)$ can be rewritten as

$$P_N(E) = \frac{1}{2} \left[1- \left(\frac{N-M}{N+M}\right)^{N}\right]$$

which is the result you were looking for since $1 - \frac{2M}{N+M}=\frac{N-M}{N+M}$.

Comment: Hello Florian, merci beaucoup! Could you please explain more about the $r = \frac{b}{1-a}$ and the formula $p_n = a^{n} (p_0 - r) +r$ ?

Comment: Sure! I just edited my answer accordingly.